# Ignoring comment in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have made the following program:

```
program test;

uses crt;

var
  Input: text;
  Line: string;
  CharCount: Integer;

procedure FindIdentifiers(Line: string);
var
  Word: string;
  WordFound: Boolean;
  NumberFound: Boolean;

begin
  Word := '';
  WordFound := false;
  NumberFound := false;
  for CharCount := 1 to Length(Line) do
  begin
    if Line[CharCount] in [' ', '.', ',', '+', '-', '''', '*', '=', '!', '?',
      ':', ';', '(', ')', '/', '\', '[', ']', '^', '>', '<'] then
    begin
      if WordFound then
      begin
        if not NumberFound then
        begin   
          writeln(Word);    
        end;
        WordFound := false;
        NumberFound := false;
        Word := '';
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      if not WordFound then
      begin
        if Line[CharCount] in ['0' .. '9'] then
          NumberFound := true
        else
          WordFound := true;
      end;
      Word := Word + Line[CharCount];
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  assign(Input, 't.pas');
  reset(Input);

  while not eof(Input) do
  begin
    readln(Input, Line);

    FindIdentifiers(Line);
  end;

  repeat
  until keypressed;    
end.
```

and input for this program is:

```
program p;
var i:integer;
{
this is comment
}
begin
end.
```

It have to ignore that comments but not delete just ignore..
Output have to be like that:

```
program
p
var
i
integer
begin
end
```

The actual output is:

```
program
p
var
i
integer
this
is
end
```

Comment: And what *is* your output with this code?

Comment: Your "if Line[CharCount] in [" does not account for the fact that the current character might a "{" or a "}".  Changing that might help your immediate problem, but will not solve the general problem of how to handle the situation where a quoted string includes either of those characters, which may be what whoever has set you this exercise might be hoping you will think about.

Comment: You need to keep state about if you are currently inside a comment or not. One thing to consider is changing your program to be structured more like a proper lexer - that is, read and tokenise, and keep state as you go. Write out the tokens found as you go, unless you are currently inside a comment. (Btw, what are the booleans FoundWord and FoundNumber for? I can't see that they actually have any effect.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please re-read your own question and observe that you haven't actually *asked a question*. What do you want to know? What part of your task are you having trouble with? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Have a look at a tokenizer like the one in DelphiAST, just google for: github DelphiAST.